# Didn't attend court for speeding in the US 11 years ago, will this cause problems now?

Tags: usa, legal, polish-citizens

I was working and traveling in California. I was caught by police for speeding.

On my ticket was the date of a court appearance. The date on ticket stated December, but I had to leave the USA in October (visa expired). All above happened 11 years ago. Can I came back to California without any problems at the border now? I'm from Poland.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/995/what-happens-when-a-foreigner-gets-a-traffic-fine-in-the-united-states

Comment: Closely related: [Any trouble at Florida customs for not paying a California speeding ticket from 5 years ago?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45501/any-trouble-at-florida-customs-for-not-paying-a-california-speeding-ticket-from)  Note that the previous question dealt with traveling to a different U.S. state, whereas this question deals with traveling to the same U.S. state (which is even riskier).

Comment: Also see [Caught speeding 111 Mph (179 km/h) in California. How can I settle the case with the court?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90636/caught-speeding-111-mph-179-km-h-in-california-how-can-i-settle-the-case-with/90679)

Comment: You need to contact the county courthouse (where you received the ticket) to find out if you have an active warrant. You can probably email them. Where did you get your ticket specifically? What road/city/area of California?